# foreach over array of objects with matching attribute

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of objects I'm using to create a menu, and each object has the properties id, video_id and chapter_id.

I'd like to make a for each loop such as

```
foreach($menu_objects as $object WHERE $object->chapter == $variable)
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: paste some sample data of $menu_objects

Comment: Probably easiest just to have a if test inside the foreach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't offer syntax like that, however, you could always make it an `if`-statement as the first line in the loop:

```
foreach ($menu_objects as $object) {
    if ($object->chapter != $variable) continue;
    ... process as normal ...
```

Comment: +1, I like this style best because it reduces nesting and it makes immediately clear to the developer that items like that will not be processed (you don't have to read to the end of the `if` block to see that).

Comment: By far the best solution. Simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

just nest an if in your loop:

```
foreach($menu_objects as $object){
  if($object->chapter == $variable){
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ways

```
foreach(array_filter($menu_objects, function($o) { return $o->chapter == $variable}) as $object)
```

Or

```
foreach($menu_objects as $o)
{
    if ($o->chapter == $variable)
    {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if?

```
foreach($menu_objects as $object) {
   if ($object->chapter == $variable) {
      // Do Something?
   }
}
```